# rst2pdf AttributeError: 'PDFWriter' object has no attribute 'custom_cover'

Tags: python, python-sphinx, rst2pdf

Cant' create PDF's anymore, earlier I could but then I guess I messed up my python installation on my mac...

I run this command:

```
sphinx-build -D language=de -b pdf /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sakkadentrainer/doc/ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sakkadentrainer_medical_doc/pdf/de/

/usr/local/bin/sphinx-build:11: RemovedInSphinx20Warning: sphinx.main()has moved tosphinx.cmd.build.main(). sys.exit(main()) 

Sphinx v1.8.5 in Verwendung Lade Übersetzungen 
[de]…erledigt Lade pickle Umgebung...erledigt 
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date building [pdf]: targets for 23 source files that are out of date updating environment: 
0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed looking for now-outdated files... none found processing Sakkadentrainer_Dokumentation_de_v1.0... index faq medical_product registration payment login pw_forgot general_training car train dot img1 img3 statistics statistics_details settings settings_profile settings_general settings_display settings_exercises settings_change_pwd settings_del eyetracking resolving references... done writing Sakkadentrainer_Dokumentation_de_v1.0... 

[ERROR] pdfbuilder.py:149 'PDFWriter' object has no attribute 'custom_cover' Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/beatgurtner/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/rst2pdf/pdfbuilder.py", line 146, in write docwriter.write(doctree, destination) 
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docutils/writers/__init__.py", line 78, in write self.translate() File "/Users/beatgurtner/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/rst2pdf/pdfbuilder.py", line 595, in translate log.error("Can't find cover template %s, using default"%self.custom_cover) 
AttributeError: 'PDFWriter' object has no attribute 'custom_cover' FAILED build abgeschlossen.
```

Description of problem
Don't know the steps to reproduce the problem... (sorry)

I tried reinstalling rst2pdf. This worked without any errors.

I tried reinstalling pdfbuilder:
Could only uninstall it. When I wanted to reinstall it I got this error:

```
pip install pdfbuilder
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pdfbuilder (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pdfbuilder
```

Versions

python -V
`Python 2.7.10`

pip freeze | grep rst2pdf
`rst2pdf==0.96`

pip freeze | grep reportlab
`reportlab==3.5.42`

pip freeze | grep Sphinx
`Sphinx==1.8.5`

Which operating system are you using?
`MacOS Mojave 10.14.1 (18B75)`

Comment: Do you really need https://pypi.org/project/pdfbuilder/? This library requires Python 3.5, but you use Python 2.7.

Comment: I think i need it. But also i have the impression its not really the problem of rst2pdf or pdfbuilder but about my python version...

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Python 2 is not maintained anymore and everyone should move to Python 3.

Comment: There was a bug that was fixed in rst2pdf 0.97. See https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf/issues/601.

Comment: The 601 issue did not help... I know Pythin 2 is EOL, but it was still working. I also have Python 3.7.7 installed...

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the problem with those steps:

```
brew upgrade sphinx-doc
pip3 install -U sphinx
pip3 install sphinx-rtd-theme
pip3 install --user rst2pdf
```

But now I really am confused, wether now I use python3 or 2 :D

Anyway, my script seems to be running again

Comment: Versions of rst2pdf at 0.97 and later are python3-only. I am not sure it helps your issue but it might help future readers with the same question/error!